# Excel: organizing inaccurate data collected by a recognition engine. I would like to calculate time worked from time first and last seen

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have a large spreadsheet of data collected by an experimental recognition engine. It collects **time started** and **time finished** data according to facial data. The issue I have is that the varying angles and lighting cause the recognition system to think that one person is two or three (or in one particular case, 12). I have gone through and manually edited the spreadsheet to contain the correct names of workers, but I would like to calculate the hours worked by each person.

Currently, the spreadsheet looks like this:

```
Name        Date                    Time Started            Time Finished

Person A    17/05/2016 10:30:20 AM  17/05/2016 10:30:20 AM  17/05/2016 10:41:18 AM
Person A    17/05/2016 10:41:20 AM  17/05/2016 10:41:20 AM  17/05/2016 10:41:20 AM
Person A    17/05/2016 11:07:09 AM  17/05/2016 11:07:09 AM  17/05/2016 11:55:24 AM
Person B    17/05/2016 10:58:30 AM  17/05/2016 10:58:30 AM  17/05/2016 10:58:30 AM
Person B    17/05/2016 10:58:42 AM  17/05/2016 10:58:42 AM  17/05/2016 10:58:42 AM
Person C    17/05/2016 10:28:05 AM  17/05/2016 10:28:05 AM  17/05/2016 11:19:28 AM
Person C    17/05/2016 10:30:26 AM  17/05/2016 10:30:26 AM  17/05/2016 11:52:56 AM
Person C    17/05/2016 10:43:30 AM  17/05/2016 10:43:30 AM  17/05/2016 11:27:20 AM
```

This is a sample of the code, but it goes up to Person Q.

I have arranged it in order of time last seen, so basically I would like to add a column that subtracts the final time worked from the initial time worked.

For each name, the correct Hours Worked can be calculated by subtracting the first `Time Started` entry from the last `Time Finished` entry. So in this example, I can find the time worked by `Person C` by doing: `17/05/2016 11:27:20 AM` - `17/05/2016 10:28:05 AM`.

So far I have been doing this by hand, but I would much prefer a function that can look at data in the `Name` column, and then calculate the `Hours Worked` by looking for the first `Time Started` entry and subtracting it from the last `Time Finished` entry.

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to do this in Excel? If not, is such a thing possible in Excel-VBA?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried various formula to extract Date and Time data like the effort shown inthe image given below.
Full formula used in `D1` was

```
=(DATE(MID(TRIM(C1),7,4),MID(TRIM(C1),4,2),MID(TRIM(C1),1,2))+TIME(MID(TRIM(C1),12,2),MID(TRIM(C1),15,2),MID(TRIM(C1),18,2))-=DATE(MID(TRIM(B1),7,4),MID(TRIM(B1),4,2),MID(TRIM(B1),1,2))+TIME(MID(TRIM(B1),12,2),MID(TRIM(B1),15,2),MID(TRIM(B1),18,2)))
```

Then Difference as shown in `D1` and `E1` was leading to erroneous results perhaps due to external data and system native features. Though I am able to get correct results by taking trimmed string only containing Date and Time portion but it will require adjustments for `AM/PM`

[image: Sample with formulas]

Looking into these problems I suggest another approach, if it is conveinient for you to adopt.

- Copy / Paste your sheet data to Note Tab Light, a free text editor and save it as a text file.
- Import in Excel the saved text file with fixed delimiters but remove delimiting bar between date and time portion leaving the rest as it is.
- Put simple formula in I3 for time difference between Time Finished and Time Started i.e. `=G3-E3`
- You can total by native Excel function on Person wise grouping.
  Sample data image as follows.

[image]

Comment: You are adding all the elapsed times.  I don't think that is what he is asking for.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld  You are right. I think I have not gone through the question carefully. I have high regards for your experience and knowledge. I would appreciate, if you can indicate why I am getting wrong elapsed time with the formula used by me in Date function.

Comment: You are getting incorrect values because the values stored in the cells are not date strings.  Excel stores dates as serial numbers usually starting at `1 Jan 1900`.  So your `MID` function is returning parts of a value that might really be `42507.4377314815` and not the Date string you expect.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Thanks for your advice. I shall correct my formulas accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Add a column to your table. Call it `Elapsed`

In the Formulas below, note that I used Named Ranges.  You can either do the same; replace them with absolute addresses; or, if your data is in a Table, replace them with the appropriate structured references.

In Excel 2016:

```
=MAXIFS(Time_Finished,Name,$A2)-MINIFS(Time_Started,Name,$A2)
```

In earlier versions you will need to enter a somewhat different formula as an array-formula.  You do this by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`

```
=MAX(IF($A2=Name,Time_Finished))- MIN(IF($A2=Name,Time_Started))
```

This will give you an output looking like this:

[image]

You can then group by person in a variety of ways, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

A pivot table is your friend here. I'm not sure how your date/time field is formatted, so in my screen shot I've divided into date and time fields for the start and end date/times.
Pivot the table which consists of the names and the start and end date/time stamps.
Row= Names
Values = the end date; end time; start date; start time
For each value, click on the drop-down and select 'Field Value Settings'.
For the end date/time select the 'Max' values.
For the start date/time select the 'Min' values. 
Then just put in a simple formula, and format it to be a time.
[Screenshot of excel pivot table showing setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INwY4.png)